# How to run my meteor app using a forked meteor version?

Tags: meteor

I have fixed a bug in meteor and while waiting for the pull-request to be accepted, I would like my up to run on that fork.

Normally it would be possible to do when using meteorite, simply by adding the URL to fork in `smart.json`, however I wonder if since Meteor 0.9, there is a better way that does not involve meteorite?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you fixed. If it was something in a package, you could just run your updated version locally.

Comment: @DavidWeldon you mean to add a copy of the package into the `packages` directory? I am just trying this now. However I am afraid that that package is not compatibly with the latest release as its based on the devel branch. Can  at least tell meteor to run on the official devel branch?

Answer (score 0):

You get the code, and simple point to `meteor` executable inside the folder of the forked code.

> "~/path_to_code/meteor" run

Comment: It has to work with with the standard meteor tool, ie `meteor run`, so that when I push this to other members of the team, they will seamlessly run on the correct fork and when the app is the deployed, the meteor builder will use the correct fork too.

Comment: Create a start script and make it the new standard across your dev team. It's handy for exporting env variables and loading Meteor.settings. I forked Chris Mather's to include ability to define a port https://github.com/rhyslbw/meteor-start

Comment: @RhysBartels-Waller we are already using iron cli. It is a lot of hastle to download that fork.